# React Router Redirect from index '/' unable to go back to previous website

Tags: react-router-v4

Our React app does not have a '/' index route, when '/' is hit it always redirects to '/plan' using this code:

```js
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

<Switch>
  <Redirect exact from="/" to="/plan" />
  <Route path="/plan" component={PlanPage} />
</Switch>
```

Our problem now is when a user is on url 'google.com' and then goes to our website he is redirected to /plan but then if the user presses the back button in the browser it goes to '/' and then back to '/plan' while we would like for the user to then return to 'google.com'.

Does anybody know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: According to the `react-router`. is the `<Redirect />` in a <Switch />`?

Comment: @Claeusdev Yes the the definitions are in a Switch, I updated the question to show the entire routes definition.

Comment: So i think the `exact` prop on the `"/"` route is preventing the history from changing.. can you try taking it out? Mostly because anytime you hit google.com your browser is treating it as a "/" and then redirecting to /plan.

Comment: Removing the exact prop didn't fix it, but it made me look at another piece of code which seems to be the culprit. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Removing the exact prop didn't fix it, but it made me look at another piece of code which seems to be the culprit. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code I posted turned out to work as expected, the culprit was our custom middleware that made use of 'connected-react-router':

```js
import {LOCATION_CHANGE} from 'connected-react-router';

export default store => next => action => {
  const {dispatch} = store;
  if (action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE) {
    dispatch(someAction());
    return next(action);
  }else {
    return next(action);
  }
};
```

Doing next(action) first and then dispatching our action fixed the problem:

```js
if (action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE) {
    next(action);
    dispatch(someAction());
  }else {
    return next(action);
  }
```